# selectval = jQuery( selected ).attr("value") only getting first number

Tags: jquery

why am i only getting getting 6356 into #id_OnPage? there are of course more LI.

I'm getting the rigth li, but only the first number..

```
<ol id="pageselect" class="ui-selectable">
        <li value="6356,6145,6296,6211,6147,6149,6152,6155,6158,6160">page 1</li></ol>

jQuery( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function(i, selected) {
  jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
  selectval = jQuery( this ).attr("value");
  jQuery('#id_OnPage').val(selectval);
});
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of notes, `<li value="">` is deprecated, and not supported by HTML 4+.  Since you're using jquery already, you can just store your data (via jQuery) in your li.  So, you could do something like:

**HTML**

```
<li id="page1">page1</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Store
$('#page1').data('value', '6356,6145,6296,6211,6147,6149,6152,6155,6158,6160');
```

Then you can access it, like:

```
$('#page1').data('value')
```